# cakephp updating form or hitting dont save changes button

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with dont save button in my app.
The scenario is:

I hit edit button on a facility, delete the name and dont want to save the changes. However if I delete the name and click "dont save", it stores an empty new name. How to avoid this?

here is the code if edit.ctp

```
<input id="subcategory" name="name" size="36" type="text" value="<?php echo $f['Whatever']['name'];?>"  />
<div id="name_error" style="color: red;"></div>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return whatevername();">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  Save
</button>
```

Saving a new name works well, validation function works also okay. Now the cancel button:

```
    <a href="<?php echo h($this->Html->Url(array('controller'=>'whatever','action'=>'view'))); ?>">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Cancel the changes
</button>
</a>
```

Any sugestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the button, use stylized link that will take you back to the reference page.